# Cannot Install R Language

Tags: r

I had R 3.6.3 installed recently. Then I installed the new R 4.0.0. I asked for the version at the command prompt and got back:

```
--------
r : Cannot locate the history for command line --version.
At line:1 char:1
+ r --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (--version:String) [Invoke-History], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeHistoryNoHistoryForCommandline,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeHistoryCommand
---------
```

I tried everything to fix it. Deleting everything R and then installing. NO change. I also was using RStudio but the R/RGui download appears to be the problem.

Comment: you need to find a way to delete the residual files from your computer's registry. Just search on google "How to delete remainder of a program from registry"

Comment: I used Avast to clear the registry up, but no change. I tried downloading R 4.0.0 (https://cran.r-project.org/index.html) on another PC and the same thing, the command prompt doesn't recognize it. I tried using another Mirror (U.S.) and same thing, the command prompt doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I see! The problem was not the installation. The problem was "R --version". That's only on Linux. I could just use "version". Plus I thought that R works on the regular windows command prompt and PowerShell. I guess not. This may be my first obstacle in learning R and Python as the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try R --version

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

Comment: I think I worked it out: "R --version" is for Linux. I'm on windows. I see that RStudio and RGui doesn't recognize "R --version". So it must just be on linux.

Comment: Could you explain how this answer helps with the question?

Comment: If you are in Linux and you try r --version, it would not work. Only upper case works. It seems stupid but it did happen to me.